# After converting MotionEvent to position, how to determine which list item was referred to in an expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, gesturedetector

I have an `ExpandableListView`, with a custom adapter, and in my gesture detector I am trying to figure out how to find the list item selected by a gesture.

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        int itemnum = listView.pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
        itemnum -= listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

So, if itemnum=7 it may be

```
group A label
group B label
item B1
item B2
group C label
item C1
item C2
item C3 <== this is position 7, assuming group A label was still on the screen
```

So, if group B was collapsed then itemnum 7 would be be C5 or D1.

Given a particular position number, how do I determine which group position and child position it refers to?

If I knew which group was expanded, then I could loop through, counting each item, but if the list has scrolled then the earlier ones shouldn't be counted.

So, given a `MotionEvent` on an `ExpandableListView` how do I convert that to the `View` that was acted upon?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Not certain if it is the best approach.

```
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        int itemnum = listView.pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                    int itemnum2 = itemnum - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View vi = listView.getChildAt(itemnum2);
```

So this is how I get the view.

Unfortunately, in order to find the child record, which in my case is a `File` I had to loop, after I retrieved the `TextView` from `vi` above:

```
                String filename = textView.getText().toString();
                int groupCount = mAdapter.getGroupCount();
                for(int t = 0; t < groupCount; t++) {
                        int childCount = mAdapter.getChildrenCount(t);
                        for(int y = 0; y < childCount; y++) {
                            File f = (File) mAdapter.getChild(t, y);
                            if (f.getName().equals(filename)) {
                            }
                        }
                }
```